# Have different Android lintOptions for different gradle tasks

Tags: android, gradle, android-lint

I want to run the Android Lint both locally (IDE) and on the CI.

I have a task like this, which I want the `abortOnError` as `true` when run on CI but `false` when ran locally.

```
task lintCI {

outputs.upToDateWhen { false }

subprojects.each { project ->
    dependsOn(project.tasks.matching { (it.name == 'lint') })
}}
```

I have tried

```
project.android {
    lintOptions {
      warningsAsErrors true
      abortOnError false
    }
}
```

but I am getting `Android tasks have already been created.`

Any Idea how to change these options per task ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for anyone searching for an answer to this, I failed to "override" this setting, but I was able to separate the behavior between the local machiene and the CI by adding a check of an environment variable (`isCI`), and based on this condition I was setting the `abortOnError`.